# jQuery scrollTop only working while scrolling with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigationbar that decreases in size when I scroll down on the page and then it takes its normal size when scroll is at the top. It all works fine when scrolling with the mousescrollwheel, but when I manually click and drag the scrollbar on the page its as if it doesnt recognise the scrollTop value. It takes approx 5 seconds or so for it to realise that its on the top and then applies the style, whereas with the mousescrollwheel it works flawlessly.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPosition > "1") {
        $("#topNav").animate({
            height: "30px"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
        $("#topNav li").animate({
            padding: "5px 0 0 0"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
    } else if (scrollPosition <= "1") {
        $("#topNav").animate({
            height: "50px"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
        $("#topNav li").animate({
            padding: "15px 0 0 0"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: change `$(document).scrollTop();` into `$(window).scrollTop();`

Comment: No, that didnt do it.

Comment: @Nub pls share a fiddle

Comment: @dpanshu Im entirely new to fiddle's, but I think that this one should be correct, although on it the scrollresize doesnt work at all, but I copypasted all the code into it, have a look at it.

https://jsfiddle.net/vtuewtu3/1/

Comment: I think it might be animation queue buildup. Using the scrollbar fires quite a few scroll events, where mousewheel only triggers a single one. Try adding a `.stop()` like `$("#topNav").stop().animate({`. Another optimisation would be to add a flag (a simple boolean serving as a switch) inside the conditional statement and use that to only apply the animation when it isn't already happening or finished.

Comment: Or add this as the first line inside the handler : `if ($('#topNav').is(':animated')) return;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and decided to go with CSS classes instead, using transitions and it worked wonders. Now what the scroll does is just add and remove class to the li elements and nav. Thansk for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$(window).on('scroll mousedown mouseup mousemove',function(){

  var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPosition > "1") {
        $("#topNav").animate({
            height: "30px"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
        $("#topNav li").animate({
            padding: "5px 0 0 0"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
    } else if (scrollPosition <= "1") {
        $("#topNav").animate({
            height: "50px"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
        $("#topNav li").animate({
            padding: "15px 0 0 0"
        }, 90, function () {

        });
    }
})
```

Comment: No, that didnt do it.

Comment: Using `mousemove` anywhere inside `window` doesn't seem like a good idea - it will fire *a lot* that way and may even start jamming things up at some point.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, scroll function is called whenever your mouse is over the scroll bar, even without click/drag event. It might be this is causing you the trouble.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x4zpekas/2/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition > "1") {
      alert('a');
    } else if (scrollPosition <= "1") {
        alert('a');
    }
});
```